# WP Custom Tabs System- Multiple Loops for Multiple Custom Post Types

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I'm building a Wordpress site right now and I'm trying to create a tab structure on a single page where I can create a sort of sub-menu and display 4 different custom-post-type loops, depending on what menu item is selected. I've been able to get the nav-items block consistent with a foreach loop, and the content blocks are switching correctly, but right now, each content div is displaying all the posts of every custom-post-type that I have.

I've experimented with switch statements and if statements as well as the is_singular conditional tag, but nothing is working quite right thus far

I've put comments in the code to delineate for myself what each section is doing, thought they might help you get into my brain space.

```
        <ul class="tab" role="tablist">
        <?php 

      //All public posts that are not built into Wordpress

        $argsnav = array(
         'public'   => true,
         '_builtin' => false,
        );

      $output = 'objects'; // names or objects, note names is the default
      $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

      //Get the Post Types of each post as an object 
      $post_types = get_post_types( $argsnav, $output, $operator ); 

      //Remove Product from Array
      unset( $post_types ['product'] );

      //Iterate through each post type
      foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {

      //And print out a list item with the corresponding ID and text
      echo '<li> 
                <a href="#' . $post_type->name . '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> 
                '. $post_type->label .'
                </a> 
            </li>'; 
      } 
      echo '</ul>';
      ?>

     //New section for post content/ This is the buggy portion
     <div class="tab-content">
     <?php

      //Iterate through each post type
        foreach($post_types as &$post_type) { ?>

      <!--Create div with corresponding id-->
        <div class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo "$post_type->name" ?>">

      <!--Create new query for all posts of each type-->       
        <?php $loop = new WP_Query(
              array(
                  'post_type' => array('standup', 'novels', 'short_stories', 'music'),
              )); 

      //Loop through and display each post's title
      if ( $loop->have_posts()) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        $loop->the_post();  ?>

            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

      <!--Stop the loop-->
      <?php endwhile;  ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
      <?php } wp_reset_postdata();  ?>


      </div>
```

I think I know *what* needs to be done, but HOW is where I'm stuck. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As I feel, you do not need to set all post_type in wp_query, please try this

```
   <!--Create new query for all posts of each type-->       
        <?php $loop = new WP_Query(
              array(
                  'post_type' => $post_type->name,
              )); 

      //Loop through and display each post's title
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, I see now how by setting them all, I was putting all the post types in there instead of letting the query call for it individually. Much appreciated!